How to add simple JSON API to Vite?
I just need to return simple JSON response for /api/status: { "ok": true }.
Something like:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    route: ('/api/status', (req, res) => {
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ ok: true }))
    })
  }
})

Vite has the proxy option, but I don't want to manually start and stop another server every time I run Vite.

What are you actually planning to deploy? Typically it would just be statically-served HTML/JS/CSS/assets, and Vite is not your web server (but there's nothing stopping you having e.g. a ./public/api/status file containing that JSON).

Seems like adding this snippet to vite config works. It configured as a proxy, but bypass everything to a custom handler.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ...

  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3001',
        bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          res.end(JSON.stringify({ ok: true }))
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ...
}


How do you plan to use this in production, where you use Vite to compile static files instead of having the Vite server running as a continuous process?

@MartinBean in production there's the real server that handles /api/status. With vite dev I need just a stub.
